# which log4j appender should be considered

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have batch java program. It will run every 1 hour.

I want to know what is the correct log4j appender for following cases:

1) creating a fresh log file every time when the job runs. meaning that log contains for that particular run only and should not contain old run data.
2) maintain same log file for that day. if next day , then create fresh file

Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/RollingFileAppender.html) allows you to define how often you want a fresh log to be created, if you add the `append=false` parameter, the log will get truncated every time it's opened,

```
log4j.appender.LOG=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOG.File=/path/to/your/file
log4j.appender.LOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOG.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.LOG.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.LOG.append=false
```

You can try [DailyRollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) too, which rolls every day by default, if none of those quite fit your needs you can always write your own Appender implementation by extending one of the [standard implementations](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/Appender.html).

Comment: Thanks @Camilo Bermúdez, I will try and accept your answer after some time.